# SkaDate admin panel lock

Tags: php

I have installed **SkaDate**, but it's creating `auth.php` creating error. I am getting the error:

> bruce attack account is locked.

Its having auth.php file for validating login details.
Although in MySQL database value for admin username and password same I enter then also getting this error.
SkaDate is a dating software package.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this notification, go through $internal_c/lang/config.php file

find the code around line number 7469 this code looks something similar to this.

```
'try_number' => 
      SK_ConfigDtoObject::__set_state(array(
         'config_id' => '208',
         'config_section_id' => '63',
         'name' => 'try_number',
         'value' => 5,
         'presentation' => 'integer',
         'description' => NULL,
         'php_validation' => NULL,
         'js_validation' => NULL,
      )),
```

Here, set the value to zero, like

```
     'try_number' => 
      SK_ConfigDtoObject::__set_state(array(
         'config_id' => '208',
         'config_section_id' => '63',
         'name' => 'try_number',
         'value' => 0,
         'presentation' => 'integer',
         'description' => NULL,
         'php_validation' => NULL,
         'js_validation' => NULL,
      )),
```

Also set the lock_stamp attribute to zero, like

```
'lock_stamp' => 
  SK_ConfigDtoObject::__set_state(array(
     'config_id' => '206',
     'config_section_id' => '63',
     'name' => 'lock_stamp',
     'value' => 0,
     'presentation' => 'integer',
     'description' => NULL,
     'php_validation' => NULL,
     'js_validation' => NULL,
  )
```

And the last step is, in the config table, search the config_section_id (here it's 63, see above code) and change the values of 'try_number' and 'lock_stamp' attributes to zero.

This should solve your problem....

Comment: @Nenotlep here we are manually resetting the bruteforce login check counter..there is already a function for that, but sometimes that does not work..

Answer (score 0):

I can't locate you in our database, so please let me know your Client IDs in SkaDate system. We are more than happy to help you with any issues we'll be glad to answer any of your questions. Just visit www.skadate.com and drop us a line.